# custom-taxonomy/post_name instead of the default post_type/post_name

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

How to make the custom post type permalink structure like `custom-taxonomy/post_name` instead of the default `post_type/post_name`.

Notable that, the custom post type is registered from a third party plugin. And I want to change the permalink structure from the theme.